# Raise Events to the UI thread from a Task

Tags: c#, winforms, task

I have been trying to determine the proper approach to manipulate the UI from an asynchronous task. My application has become cluttered with threaded Invokes and BeginInvokes. I am trying to alleviate this clutter as well as provide a bit more responsiveness on the UI by taking advantage of [C# async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Somewhere on the UI thread I initialize [IProgress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1.report?view=netframework-4.7.2) *event handler* and pass it to an asynchronous function called `DoInfiniteWorkAsync`. This function runs infinitely in a background task but often has the need to update portions of the UI.

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // Create a UIEventHandler on our UI thread.
       Progress<string> UIEventHandler = new Progress<string>();
       UIEventHandler.ProgressChanged += UIEventHandler_CommandRaised;
       // Pass the UIEventHandler to our Asyncronous task.
       DoInfiniteWorkAsync(UIEventHandler);

   }
   void UIEventHandler_EventRaised(object sender, string e)
   {
       string eventMessage = e;
       // Update UI based on the event message.
   }
```

My `DoInfiniteWorkAsync` function uses the passed in `UIEventHandler` to report `UIEventMessages` while running its task.

```
    private async Task DoInfiniteWorkAsync(IProgress<string> UIEventHandler)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // 24/7 running tasks. 
            // Sets a UIEventMessage to signal UI thread to do something.
            UIEventHandler.Report(UIEventMessage);
        });
    }
```

Is this the proper way to be updating the UI thread from a long running background thread? The fact that my *event handler* datatype (IProgress) is specifically directed at progress reporting is making me feel like I'm missing the point.

Comment: is this winforms or uwp?  It looks to be winform

Comment: Try `Control.Invoke`.

Comment: Firing repeated update events from the worker thread to the UI thread is just as likely to slow your app again and put you in the same place as before.  Don't use `Control.Invoke`, it blocks the worker thread whilst waiting for the UI to respond.  The worker thread should not care.  Also, Control.Invoke can lead to a thread deadlock.  It is arguably much better to have the work thread simply set a `bool` flag somewhere that the UI thread can check during application idle.  Not only is it more efficient but more importantly, the UI only updates *once* even if the worker thread set it many times

Comment: Unless you are doing this _very_ often, `Control.Invoke` is your friend here. To remove clutter, create a method that does the UI update, and in that method test if `Control.InvokeRequired`. If so, Invoke that same method. If you do that, the method is callable from any thread; the UI thread or sny background thread. You should be able to find lots of sample code that does this - it's a very common call pattern

Answer (score 0):

To bring in data from one asynchronous thread to another you have to invoke it.

Define in your class a field of property:

```
    string _readData = null;
```

Then fill the string with the eventMessage and call a method to invoke the data.

```
string eventMessage = e;
_readData = eventMessage;
Msg();
```

This is the method Msg():

```
    private void Msg()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(Msg));
        }
        else
        {
            textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + Environment.NewLine + " >> " + _readData;
        }
    }
```

Comment: To remove all ambiguity:
the receiving thread exposes an event handler. (here: Msg()).

the calling thread needs to access that handler.

the handler in the receiving thread must be changed as described above.

Now the calling thread can directly call the handler.
This 'pattern' is used often if threads interact with callbacks.
The sending thread exposes a callback Delegate.

The receiving thread wants to handle the callback and therefore binds its handler to the Delegate.